# Observable returning data as expected but variable is still undefined

Tags: angular, angular-http, angular-httpclient

In my Angular app, I am subscribing to an Observable below:

```
 ngOnInit() {

    let readerID: number = parseInt(this.route.snapshot.params['id']);

    this.dataService.getReaderById(readerID)
    .subscribe(
      (data: Reader) => this.selectedReader = data,
      (err: any) => console.log(err)
    );
      console.log('SELECTED READER: ' + this.selectedReader);   }
```

When the user moves to this page, a **Reader ID** is passed in the route & populates some input fields with that Reader info.

But, this is also logged to the console:

> SELECTED READER: undefined

I thought that my code was meant to assign the retrieved data to the **selectedReader** variable, so I'm not sure why it's logging as **UNDEFINED**.

Can someone please tell me why this is happening, even though the reader details are being displayed? Why is the **selectedReader** actually undefined?

Comment: See the aforementioned [suggested duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/1260204). Asynchronous calls are a common and critical building block in writing/designing an application. It is critical that you understand how to work with asynchronous calls in javascript, and by extension typescript. Understanding these core concepts will help you become a better programmer and also ensure you do not keep "stubbing your toe" on the same problem.

Comment: @Igor thanks for your help. So am I correct in saying that the reason `selectedReader` is being returned as _undefined_ is because the code hasn't actually returned the reader details yet & it has moved on to execute the next line?

Comment: That is correct. If you want to access this property after it has been assigned a value you should move that line of code to inside the subscribe method/callback. So `this.selectedReader = data` becomes `{ this.selectedReader = data;  console.log('SELECTED READER: ' + this.selectedReader); }`